# Maximum call stack size exceeded in node.js

Tags: node.js

Here is my node.js application with mongodb, the code blew works well, simply to load the user information from mongodb database through a user session id, and the session store is MongoStore from [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo). Initially, this node.js is deployed locally in my computer.

However, when I clicked the browser to get the page refreshed very fast, after some clicks(20,30 clicks) it will throw a exception, saying
 **uncaught exception: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**
and sometimes, it additionally show another error, saying Error: no open connections on the connect-mongo

```
app.get('/',homePage);

function homePage(req,res){
    var locals = {};    

    userModel.findUserById(req.session.uid,function(err,user){
                    if(err) {
                        console.log('user uid not found'.red);
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log('find user uid'.green,user._id);
                        locals.user = {
                           username: user.username,
                           email: user.email
                        };
                        res.send(200);
                    }
    })  
}
```

Here is the findUserById called by the userModel, which is in another file.

```
function findUserById(id,callback){
        var id;
        try {
             id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id);
        } catch(e) {
                callback(err, null);
        }

        UserModel.findById(id,function(err, doc){
            if(err){callback(err, null);}
            else{
                callback(null, doc);
            }
        })  
    }
```

I don't know what really goes wrong, is it connect-mongo or something else, I found the error of maximum call stack size exceeded is because of recursion, but the code I have shown here has no recursion.

> **update:**

```
app.get('/',homePage);

function homePage(req,res){
    var locals = {};    
    res.send(200);
}
```

even in this situation, after click fast in many times, the server will also throw a error of **Maximum call stack size exceeded**

I guess it is because of my node.js version and express not compatible enough? my express version is 3.1.0 but my node.js version is 0.8.20?

Comment: Also in your `findUserById` function: If you catch an error I'll guess you won't query the database anyway. You your code callback could be triggered twice.

Comment: so I should put a return after callback(err, null), or just do like : return callback(err, null);

Comment: I don't see how your updated code could cause that error, unless your app consists of more than just that code and the error occurs somewhere in there. Hard to debug without more context.

Comment: Move all code in the try catch block. It won't get so far, if an error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Now as I update the node.js version to the lastest version 10.4, the problem doesn't seem to happen again, so the reason is probably because of the old node.js version can't work with latest express version.

I always update the library version, but leave the node.js not updated.

Comment: I've used Express 3 together with Node 0.8 without any problems, but good to hear the problem is solved now :)